# NUnit, can "setup" run before "ValueSource"?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have the following basic setup for a uni-test: it tests a class that is responsible for indexing files in a directory, and keep giving the correct one on demand.
To do this I use a mock file system provided by `system.io.abstractions` library. The basic setup is as follows:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ImageDataTests
{
    private static MockFileSystem fs;
    private const int TESTNUM = 3;
    [SetUp]
    public static void Init() {
        var allnamegroups = TestSettings.NameGroupFactory(TESTNUM);
        fs = new MockFileSystem();
        foreach (string[] namegroup in allnamegroups) {
            var dname = ImageData.MakeDirectoryName(namegroup[0], namegroup[1]);
            TestSettings.AddTestFilesToMockFileSystem(fs, dname);
        }
    }
}
```

Now each test works on a case for this, and to test (say) a "reload" function I add the following method to above class:

```
    public static IEnumerable<ImageData> ImgDatSource() {
        while (true) {
            yield return new ImageData("test", fs);
        }
    }
    [Test, Sequential]
    public void GetAllOfTypeTest(
        [ValueSource(nameof(ImgDatSource))] ImageData img, 
        [Values("foo", "bar", "this")]string type, 
        [Values(1, 2, 0)]int ex) {
        Assert.That(() => img.GetAllOfType(type).Count(), Is.EqualTo(ex));
    }
```

This should (right now) list all files starting with respectively "foo", "bar" and "this". - It fails, stating that the directory is not found. - Even before the first test is run: at the initializing of `Imagedata`.
Debugging verifies what I thought: the `Init()` is not run yet when the `ValueSource` tries to initialize the input.

Is there a way to do "such" a test, short of initializing the `Imagedata` inside the test body? (And either losing the parametric construction + test indexing, or having to write many similar tests manually).

Notice that I really NEED to run the filesystem generator each test: while above test is simple and doesn't do much. Some tests will adapt/change the filesystem to test the class against more edge-cases. - Also during the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit's execution has two phases: loading (discovering) tests and running tests. OneTimeSetUp, SetUp, test method execution, TearDown and OneTimeTearDown are all part of running the test.

Test loading takes place, as you might expect, before running the tests. Your data sources (TestCaseSource or ValueSource) are all run during the load phase.

This leads to two conclusions:
1. It is not possible for anything in your SetUp and other test execution methods to have an effect on the data that is used for a test.
2. Your data sources need to provide data parameters that will allow you to create objects at runtime, not the objects themselves.

In your example, I would change the test method to take four parameters, replacing img with "test" and fs. I would add a line to the start of each  test to create the imagedata by calling a helper method modeled after your Init.

Comment: Could I automatically generate that line to each function in some way, maybe by running a different macro? This is code duplication and that's something I think should always be prevented.

Comment: I'm in partial agreement. Code duplication in tests is often useful because it makes each test stand on its own. In this case, though, it would be better if there were a way to avoid it. The only approach I can think of would be to parameterize the fixture and create the imagedata in the OneTImeSetUp. This may be more work than just adding the code in each method, however.